# Tableau Filtering Calculated Field

Tags: tableau-desktop, calculated-field

I have some data that has the variables Sex and NumHire and I am trying to create a caluclated field in tableau, but my experience is next to none. The goal is for the caluclated field to be the diffence in male and female combined NumHire. That is, it would be male NumHire - female NumHire. I just have yet to find a way to extrace just the male and female counts within the calculated field.

I have done some searching to learn the syntax of tableau calculated fields, but have yet to find a way to extract just the male and female counts within the calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a calculated field with the following definition.

```
SUM(IF [Sex] = "Male" THEN [NumHire]) - SUM(IF [Sex] = "Female" THEN [NumHire])
```

The implict ELSE clause evaluates to null, which is ignored by aggregation functions like SUM()

Alternatively, you could calculate the percentage of female hires as
SUM(IF [Sex] = "Female" THEN [NumHire]) / SUM([NumHire])

Then be sure to set the number format of the result as a percentage